# Track whether user has opened an email or not

Tags: php, sendmail, mailchimp

I am working with the MailChimp PHP API, and I would like to know how I would be able to track whether or not a user has viewed the email sent. I figure there might some type of code I should write in the message sent to the user. Anyhow, this is how I connect to mailchimp:

```
  // Post data retrieved from ajax post
  $fullName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fname']);
  $email =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ///////MailChimp Integration////////////////////
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Subscribe a user to MailChimp


  $MailChimp = new MailChimp('id');
  $result = $MailChimp->post('lists/id/members', array(
              'email_address'     => $email,
              'status'            => 'subscribed',
              'merge_fields'      => array('FNAME'=>$fullName, 'LNAME'=>'')
          ));


$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "<p>";

$message .= "Hi $fullName, <br><br><br>";
[..]
```

I would rather use mailchimp but if there are any other solutions let me know. I also store data in the mysql database through mysqli.

Comment: Generally it is left to the client and the user preferences as to whether or not the flag `read` gets set and informs the mailhost. In theory though if the email is html then you could create a 1px x 1px transparent image,  using php, which is hosted on your server and is included in the email body - that image can, because it is php, do all manner of reporting. This is generally known as a web bug and not considered good form.

Comment: Happily most email clients won't load remotely hosted images by default so webbugs are rendered useless.

Comment: *My 2 cents* - one thing you can do is use a trackable link. For instance; your mailout has a story about something but you don't include the full story. So... you have a link with "Read the full story", with the trackable href ;-) Kind of sneaky, but that works. The magic happens in the `WHERE` clause of your query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wonder how mailchimp traces how many user have opened an email when you sent out an email from their end. Yeah image is not enabled by default in some mailhost such as gmail, trackable href would be great although the email just provides the user with a list of resources with follow-up email to come afterwards

Comment: for this ^ I would simply use a counter incremented in the db. That's how I would do it, given I don't know "how" they do it ;-) it's their baby/system.

Comment: what I think Mailchimp does to track if a message was opened (we use Mailchimp also), is that they too probably use an image method to track and/or based on an href in the newsletter; I noticed that numbers don't increase when images are not loaded or links are not clicked. Ever notice what the href's look like in the mailout? They're not yours, they tack on special codes. *Think about it* ;-)

Comment: okay thanks, Could you elaborate more on the counter

Comment: you're welcome. The counter method is easy. Just use an `UPDATE TABLE SET col_x = col_x +1 WHERE col_y = 'something'`.

Comment: If you feel that your question has been answered (given what I suggested), I'd be glad to convert my comments to an answer in order to close the question @JonathanEtienne

Comment: sure fred that would be great

Comment: @JonathanEtienne I think you clicked the tick on my answer, but it unticked lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My 2 cents* - comments to answer.

One thing you can do is use a trackable link. For instance; your mailout has a story about something but you don't include the full story.

So... you have a link with "Read the full story", with the trackable href.

It's kind of sneaky, but that works and isn't illegal. The magic happens in the WHERE clause of your query.

What I think Mailchimp does to track if a message was opened (we use Mailchimp also), is that they too probably use an image method to track and/or based on an href in the newsletter; I noticed that numbers don't increase when images are not loaded or links are not clicked.

Ever notice what the href's look like in the mailout? They're not yours, they tack on special codes.

If the source link code you have in your mailout is `http://www.example.com/file.xxx`, then Mailchimp changes that to something like the following in order to track clicked links.

For example:
`http://yourdomain.usX.list-manage.com/track/click?u=alpha-numerical-set-of-characters`

To use a counter in MySQL, an example of this would be to use UPDATE:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET col_x = col_x +1 WHERE col_y = 'something'
```

Reference for UPDATE:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: Yes mailchimp add a image. Problem however is that most mail programs do not load images by default. They give you a warning when looking at the numbers that apple devices might seem to score high duo to the fact they do automaticly load images. Tracking clicks only shows you the click trough rate, with is A LOT lower then the amount of times a mail is opend.

Comment: @Jeroen Yes, that I am aware of. Thanks for your comment. upvoted

Comment: we do this --- but also add a check to every link on the email, it greatly increases accuracy.

Comment: @Dagon Someone else told me the same thing today also.

Comment: email metrics are an important part of my job (unfortunately)